# as.Date command in R returns NA

Tags: r, na, as.date

My date variable keeps returning a "NA" when i use the as.Date() command.

I have practically tried all the various ways, which include

(a) stating the origin argument; 
(b) setting the locale
(c) converting the original variable into characters before reading in the csv file (`read.csv("<file name>.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE`)
(d) stating the format in the as.Date argument
(e) converting the original variable into numeric

I am reading a .csv file into R.
The structure of the original variable is:

```
$ Date.Sold                : Factor w/ 30 levels "","01/10/2015",..: 1 1 1 1 1
```

I have tried to convert the `$Date.Sold` field into a date variable, so that i can ultimately extract the Year from it. The command which i am using is:

```
SP$Date.Sold = as.Date("SP$Date.Sold",format="%Y/%m/%d", origin="1899-12-30")
```

Help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SP$Date.Sold = as.Date(SP$Date.Sold,format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

but if you just want to extract the year, you can do the following:

```
SP$Date.Sold = substr(SP$Date.Sold,7,11)
```

Comment: wow it works! thanks so much :)  I am very new to R. just wondering why format="%Y/%m/%d" can't work? R will require the date to be formatted in this order: <format="%d/%m/%Y">?

Comment: @hagewhy You applied the `as.Date()` function to a string (you enclosed `SP$Date.Sold` in "") and not to the column itself. Plus the date format has to match the actual format from your column.
If my answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted.